# return value from spawned multiprocessing.process

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have a script which is subscribed to RMQ channel and it should spawn a new process with long-playing IO task if it gets some special kind of messages. And after this it should be terminated.

I've very simple function which tries to spawn worker:

```
 async def spawn_worker(self):
     p = multiprocessing.Process(target=long_plaing_task)
     p.start()
     p.join()
     result = await p.get_a_result_somehow()
     p.kill()
```

I have never worked with multiprocessing so my question is simple and maybe stupid: how should a get that result from the spawned process? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329974/can-i-get-a-return-value-from-multiprocessing-process) question and answer to use Queues. But is this the only way to get a result or there are some more convinient ways?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415028/how-can-i-recover-the-return-value-of-a-function-passed-to-multiprocessing-proce  does this help?  I have always just used queues but apparently you have other means as well.

Comment: In your example, `spawn_worker` is a coroutine, and you're using `await` to get a result from the `multiprocessing.Process`. I don't think the `multiprocessing` module supports asynchronous behavior like that.

Comment: There isn't a more convenient way to get a return value from a `multiprocessing.Process` directly, but there is if you use `multiprocessing.Pool` instead. The question @Hannu links to has an answer that covers that.

Comment: FWIW, if you need `multiprocessing` integration with `asyncio`, there is the third-party [`aioprocessing`](https://github.com/dano/aioprocessing) library (full disclosure: I am the author).

Comment: Consider using [`loop.run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.run_in_executor) with a [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor): `result = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, target, *args)`

Comment: Actually, assuming you need the `asyncio` integration, @Vincent's suggestion is probably the best choice.